# Unable to execute chrome.scripting.executeScript in background.js file

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm converting the version of manifest from 2 to 3, as we cannot use chrome.tabs.executeScript , i'm using chrome.scripting.executeScript to execute the injection

in manifest v2 I had below lines of code

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {
  code: appssoscript[0].chrome,
  runAt: 'document_start'
});
```

where appssoscript[0].chrome consists of value:

```js
document.getElementById("username").value="application_user1";
document.getElementById("password").value="Passw0rd@123";
document.querySelector(".from__button--floating").click();`
```

in manifest v3 i've changed the code to

```js
chrome.scripting.executeScript({ 
  target: {tabId: tabid},
  func : getScript,
  args : [appssoscript[0].chrome],
});
```

in above code I'm executing a function called `getScript` where I'm passing argument `appssoscript[0].chrome` but the function is not injecting values

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Remove `args` and simply put the value's inner contents (the second block in your question) into getScript as code not as a string, see [these examples](/a/67227376).

Comment: The script we are trying to inject here is coming dynamically, so we can't hardcode it
we have to capture it from the page and then we have to pass it, please let us know how to pass the value and then inject it

Answer (score -1):

Please try this.

```js
const getScript = (script) => {
  Function(script)();
}

chrome.scripting.executeScript({ 
  target: {tabId: tabid},
  world: "MAIN",
  func : getScript,
  args : [appssoscript[0].chrome]
});
```